# SwiftUI: how to set a greater than or equal constraint like UIKit's AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, swiftui

In a UIKit project, I had a constraint like this in one view:

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

I would like to do the same in SwiftUI, so I tried this:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
        Style.Color.blue
            .cornerRadius(17)
        Text(text)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(.horizontal, 11)
            .padding(.vertical, 8)
            .lineLimit(nil)
    }
}
```

I'm getting this result:

[image]

I have no idea how I can do the same than in UIKit, to apply a greather than or equal leading constraint to the blue view.
Also, as you can see, on the single line bubble the blue view doesn't stick to the text label, but instead goes to the leading part of the screen. How can I solve this?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
struct ItemView: View {
    let text: String

    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .lineLimit(nil)
            .padding(10)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(17)
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let texts = ["Short text", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            Color.clear
            VStack {
                ForEach(texts, id: \.self) { text in
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        ItemView(text: text)
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 11)
                    .padding(.vertical, 8)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that instead of `\.self` in `ForEach(texts, id: \.self)` you may want to provide a way to identify texts (if they can be non-unique).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just added a white view with a frame `.frame(width: 104, height: .infinity)` left of the `Spacer()` in the `HStack`. Don't know if this is the best way to do this, but it works.